# How to effectively hide field in Odoo 13 CE?

Tags: python, odoo-13

I'm working on Odoo 13 CE and I'm inheriting view `l10n_latam_base.view_partner_latam_form` form model `res.partner` and I cannot make the field `city` to be hidden (note that `city` belongs to the view `base.view_partner_form` which is the parent view of the view I'm inheriting from). I've already tried with the following with no luck:

```xml
<field name="city" invisible="1"/>
```

```xml
<field name="city" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': True}</attribute>
</field>
```

```xml
<field name="city" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</field>
```

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='city']" position="attributes">
    <!-- with this  -->
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
    <!-- and this -->
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': True}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

I tried to use the selector `//field[@name='city'][2]` whith `xpath` but I get an error complaining that the element couldn't be found on the parent view, this tells me there's no more than one `city` on the parent view, I guess. Another thing is that I'm using that field as reference to add some fields of my own and **IT'S WORKING**, i.e., the fields are displayed right after `city`, something like:

```xml
<field name="city" position="after">
    <!-- ... -->
</field>
```

If I use `position="replace"` in the snippet above the field `city` is replaced (but I read somewhere this is not recommended), I don't know why this field is so special that won't hide, other fields like `state_id` and `zip` are hidden correctly.

Any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is probably another expression that makes the field visible because using the third code above is enough to make the field invisible.

Comment: Any ideas of how can I find that expression? I have read both views (parent and grandparent) and I don't see anything that rings any bells about it. For the time being I'm replacing the field even though it's not recommended.

Comment: To check all the inherited views, edit the form view, and look inside the `Inherited Views` tab.

Answer (score 0):

you should use attrs if you want to hide field based on condition but if there is no condition just add attribute like this :

```
<field name="city" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</field>
```

**Note : position="replace" is critical thing because you delete this field from a form and maybe there are other fields before or after this field so be careful .**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is one of my failed attempts.

Comment: please more explain